# google analytics "Request had insufficient authentication scopes"; "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" Error

Tags: php, google-analytics, oauth, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to give access to a user in my google analytics account using api. but I am getting

> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Insufficient Permission",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
> }
> ],
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
> }
> this error.
> here is my php code.

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://analytics.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/203453755/entityUserLinks?key=[api key];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"id\":\"id:mailId\",\"kind\":\"analytics#entityUserLink\",\"selfLink\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/id/entityUserLinks/id:mailId\",\"entity\":{\"accountRef\":{\"id\":\"id\",\"kind\":\"analytics#accountRef\",\"href\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/id\",\"name\":\"abir test\"},\"webPropertyRef\":{\"id\":\"UA-webproperty\",\"kind\":\"analytics#webPropertyRef\",\"href\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/id\",\"accountId\":\"id\",\"internalWebPropertyId\":\"id\",\"name\":\"malta\"},\"profileRef\":{\"id\":\"id\",\"kind\":\"analytics#profileRef\",\"href\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/id\",\"accountId\":\"accountId\",\"webPropertyId\":\"UA-webproperty\",\"internalWebPropertyId\":\"id\",\"name\":\"All Web Site Data\"}},\"userRef\":{\"kind\":\"analytics#userRef\",\"id\":\"userEmailId\",\"email\":\"usermail@gmail.com\"},\"permissions\":{\"effective\":[\"READ_AND_ANALYZE\"],\"local\":[\"READ_AND_ANALYZE\"]}}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$google_client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer [access_token]
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result,true);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using the [Account User Links: list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/list) method.

This method requires authorization with one of the following scopes
[image]

You appear to be using the correct scope of

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users

So one of two things is happening.

Either the user you are authorizing with does not have admin access and there for can not see users themselves.  If this is the case then login with a user with admin access or upgrade this user to have admin access.

Or you have changed the scope in your application after you had already authorized the user.  If you did change the scope then you need to revoke the users access and then authorize your application again you need to see the consent scree and it should state the new scope on it.